# How to generate a password dynamically and send it to user via email in an Angular/SpringBoot application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am optimizing the authentication process for a web application whose front-end is written using Angular and a back-end API written in Spring Boot. I need to generate a password for my user and send it to their email upon registration. Where do I need to start in order to achieve this? Should it be done from my front-end or back-end?

I have created a Util class where I have a method that generates the password, as well as respective entity classes for User which have the password and email fields. I don't know how to proceed from here.

My code is as follows:

Users model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends BaseModel{

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="fullname")
private String fullName;

@Column(name="password")
private String password
```

user Service class:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

public User authUser(User user) throws Exception {
    //System.out.println(user.getPassword());
    System.out.println("User Password####"+user.getPassword());
    System.out.println("User Username####"+user.getUsername());
    return `userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.getUsername(),AES.encrypt(user.getPassword()));
}

public User addUser(User user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

public User findByUsername(String username) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}

public List<UsersToVerify> getUsersToVerify() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userRepository.getUsersToVerify();
}

public int verifyUsers(Long userId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userRepository.approveUsers(userId);
}

}
```

util class:

```
 public String randomPassword() {
    System.out.println("Generating Password");

    String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&?{}*";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int count = 8;

    while (count-- != 0) {
        int character = (int) (Math.random() * ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
        builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));
    }
    return builder.toString();

}
```

Comment: You can also generate a password using a native implementtion of UUID using `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: You don't. You generate an expiring pre-logged-in link to the change-password page and send that. You don't want anyone or anything at your end knowing the password, even temporarily. Company-breaking legal consequences can follow.

Answer (score 1):

I used spring-boot-starter-mail follow this topic and it worked with me.

You can update code in method authUser() to send generated password via email using EmailService.

Add dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Create EmailService to send email.

```
@Component
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMessage(
      String to, String subject, String text) {
        ...
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
        message.setTo(to); 
        message.setSubject(subject); 
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);
        ...
    }
}
```

Link reference https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

Comment: Is `EmailService` a class?

Comment: it is an interface, you can download source code at https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-mvc-simple

Comment: Should I reuse the same code in the util class to modify the `Auth()` method? Does it come before password encryption?